# How Can I Write Things Side By Side In The Box?

Tags: html, css

Hello guys i wanna write 1 and new referral side by side but i couldnt figure it out how. new referral will not have green background but they will be side by side any help appreciated. I shared my codes on code snippet. I wrote it by using html and css. I tried to search and ask people but got no answer. Thanks already

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;


background: #CDE7ED;
}



.heading1{
    position: absolute;
width: 449px;
height: 80px;


top: 56px;

font-family: 'Montserrat';
font-style: normal;
font-weight: 500;
font-size: 30px;
line-height: 40px;
/* or 133% */

text-align: center;

background: #FFFFFF;
color: #0B2B5B;
}

#navbar{
position: relative;
height: 196px;

top: 0px;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;

background: #FFFFFF;
}

.iki{
  
height: 32px;
left: 539px;
top: 230px;

font-family: 'Montserrat';
font-style: normal;
font-weight: 500;
font-size: 24px;
line-height: 32px;


text-align: center;

color: #0B2B5B;
}
.uc{

height: 32px;
left: 435px;
top: 270px;

font-family: 'Montserrat';
font-style: normal;
font-weight: 500;
font-size: 20px;
line-height: 32px;
/* identical to box height, or 160% */

text-align: center;

color: #0B2B5B;
}

.box{
  
    position: absolute;
    
    width: 782px;
    height: 380px;
    left: 470px;
    
    top: 334px;
    
    background: #FFFFFF;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px rgba(11, 43, 91, 0.1);
    border-radius: 4px;
}

.box-header{
   
width: 782px;
height: 64px;
left: 249px;
top: 334px;

background: #FFFFFF;
border-radius: 4px 4px 0px 0px;
}
.b1{
    
width: 40px;
height: 64px;
left: 249px;
top: 334px;

background: #25A575;
border-radius: 4px 0px 0px 0px;
}
.b11{
   
width: 10px;
height: 32px;
left: 264px;
top: 350px;

font-family: 'Montserrat';
font-style: normal;
font-weight: 500;
font-size: 26px;
line-height: 32px;


display: flex;
align-items: center;
text-align: center;
font-feature-settings: 'pnum' on, 'lnum' on;

color: #FFFFFF;
background: #25A575;
}
.new{
    
width: 132px;
height: 24px;
left: 305px;
top: 354px;

font-family: 'Montserrat';
font-style: normal;
font-weight: 500;
font-size: 20px;
line-height: 24px;
/* identical to box height, or 120% */

display: flex;
align-items: center;
font-feature-settings: 'pnum' on, 'lnum' on;

color: #3A719B;
background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.0/css/all.min.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@400;700;800&family=Oswald:wght@200;300;400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="app.js"></script>

    <header class="header">
        <div class="container">
            <nav id="navbar">
                <h1 class="heading1">Patient Referral Form Hayes Valley Health San Francisco </h1>
               
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>

    <h2 class="iki">Referral Patients</h2>
    <h3 class="uc">You can add up to five patients at a time</h3>
    <div class="box">
        <div class="box-header">
            <div class="b1">
                <div class="b11">
                    1
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="new">
                New Referral 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: on `box-header` class, use `flexbox`. `display: flex;`

Answer (score 0):

I put here the updated code :

```css
* {
  background: #cde7ed;
}

.heading1 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 449px;
  height: 80px;

  top: 56px;

  font-family: "Montserrat";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 40px;
  /* or 133% */

  text-align: center;

  background: #ffffff;
  color: #0b2b5b;
}

#navbar {
  position: relative;
  height: 196px;

  top: 0px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;

  background: #ffffff;
}

.iki {
  height: 32px;
  left: 539px;
  top: 230px;

  font-family: "Montserrat";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 32px;

  text-align: center;

  color: #0b2b5b;
}
.uc {
  height: 32px;
  left: 435px;
  top: 270px;

  font-family: "Montserrat";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 32px;
  /* identical to box height, or 160% */

  text-align: center;

  color: #0b2b5b;
}

.box {
  position: absolute;

  width: 782px;
  height: 380px;
  left: 470px;

  top: 334px;

  background: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px rgba(11, 43, 91, 0.1);
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.box-header {
  display: flex;
  width: 782px;
  height: 64px;
  left: 249px;
  top: 334px;

  background: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 4px 4px 0px 0px;
}
.b1 {
  width: 40px;
  height: 64px;
  left: 249px;
  top: 334px;

  background: #25a575;
  border-radius: 4px 0px 0px 0px;
}
.b11 {
  width: 10px;
  height: 32px;
  left: 264px;
  top: 350px;

  font-family: "Montserrat";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 26px;
  line-height: 32px;

  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  font-feature-settings: "pnum" on, "lnum" on;

  color: #ffffff;
  background: #25a575;
}
.new {
  width: 132px;
  height: 24px;
  left: 305px;
  top: 354px;

  font-family: "Montserrat";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 24px;
  /* identical to box height, or 120% */

  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  font-feature-settings: "pnum" on, "lnum" on;

  color: #3a719b;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.0/css/all.min.css"
    />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@400;700;800&family=Oswald:wght@200;300;400&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <script src="app.js"></script>

    <header class="header">
      <div class="container">
        <nav id="navbar">
          <h1 class="heading1">
            Patient Referral Form Hayes Valley Health San Francisco
          </h1>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </header>
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />

    <h2 class="iki">Referral Patients</h2>
    <h3 class="uc">You can add up to five patients at a time</h3>
    <div class="box">
      <div class="box-header">
        <div class="b1">
          <div class="b11">1</div>
        </div>
        <div class="new">New Referral</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```